# How do I find the error while using Rails and Javascript? Can't find variable: Raphael

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-3, raphael, pie-chart

I'm using rails 3 and I have this error on my safari console:

```
pie.js:1ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Raphael  pie.js  

SyntaxError: Expected token ']'  Raphael-min.js
```

The javascript is working when I'm not using rails. However, the code breaks when using rails 3. I tried using the non minified version but I also get an error. How should I approach such a problem ?

Pie.js:

```
Raphael.fn.pieChart=function(e,t,n,r,i){
function a(e,t,n,r,i,u){
    var a=e+n*Math.cos(-r*o),f=e+n*Math.cos(-i*o),l=t+n*Math.sin(-r*o),c=t+n*Math.sin(-i*o);
    return s.path(["M",e,t,"L",a,l,"A",n,n,0,+(i-r>180),0,f,c,"z"]).attr(u)}
    var s=this,o=Math.PI/180,u=this.set();
    var f=90,l=100,c=function(o){
        var c=r[o],h=360*c/l;if(r[o]==100){
            var p=s.circle(e,t,n).attr({fill:"#ea503d",stroke:"#ea503d","stroke-width":0})}
        else{if(o==1){var p=a(e,t,n,f,f+h,{fill:"90-#ea503d-#ea503d",stroke:i,"stroke-width":0})}
        else{var p=a(e,t,n,f,f+h,{fill:"90-#cecece-#cecece",stroke:i,"stroke-width":0})}
            f+=h}u.push(p)};
    for(var h=0;h<r.length;h++){c(h)}return u};
$(function(){var e=[];$(".sys_circle_progress").each(function(){
    var t=parseInt($(this).attr("data-percent"));var n=100-t;
    if(n==0){e[0]=t}else{e[0]=n;e[1]=t}
Raphael($(this).find(".sys_holder_sector")[0],78,78).pieChart(39,39,39,e,"#cecece");
$(this).append('<span class="val-progress">'+$(this).attr("data-percent")+"%</span>")})})
```

Comment: I noticed that this error is there in all the pages. Even when I do not use raphael.

Comment: In your assets -> javascript -> application.js `//require_tree .` or if you load your raphael-min.js from the vendor, and if you <%= javascript_include_tag "application" %> in your "views -> layout/application.html.erb" you will use the raphael script throughout the application and that is standard for a Rails app. Could you post your pie script?

Comment: Many thanks Aurelien for your help. It is very strange since the script works when running outside rails. This is why I think this could be maybe a conflict with other script I am loading. I will include my pie.js in my question.

Comment: Ok... this is weired. I cleared all my cache (safari, tmp/cache folder, etc..). Then I bundle updated all my gems. and now I do not have any errors. many thanks Aurelien.

Comment: The error just appeared again and I can't seam to pinpoint the problem. What I know is that it appears anywhere regardless of page content. I can't believe i'm the only one having such an error.